# Error when trying to access API endpoint of server SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel'

Tags: laravel, api, http, error-handling, configuration

I am trying to access API server for client side, I created 2 laravel folders, one for server and one for client, but when I try to access API server endpoint I got error as stated in title,but my database configuration on server side is appropriate, doesn't the client not have to connect to the database to fetch data from the endpoint server?

this is my server .env

```
APP_NAME=TEST_TIKET_BIOSKOP
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:GWdPrhK82EoxL/dYOEEzvOObOc1W+KT6SHcVePxOl+A=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://tiket-bioskop.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tiket_bioskop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

this is my client .env

```
APP_NAME=CLIENT_TIKET_BIOSKOP
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:w+rIpO76tdH9hnbz15Nzb5a4UWezRFBYIT0ndSn0IJg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL= http://tiket-bioskop-client.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

my controller in server

```
 public function dashboard()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'You On Dashboard',
            'status' => true,
            'tickets' => TiketBioskop::latest()->get()
        ],200);
    }
```

my client controller to access endpoint API

```
 public function dashboard()
    {
        
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '. session('token'),
        ])->get('http://tiket-bioskop.test/api/tickets');

        $tiket =  json_decode($response , true);
   
        return $response;
 
    }
```

server endpoint

```
 Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function(){
Route::get('/tickets' , [TiketController::class , 'dashboard']);
```

});

i was expecting $response to return the data , but as i said i got database configuration error on client side SQLSTATE[HY000][1049] Unknown database 'laravel'..... but when i change my DB configuration in client side from `DB_DATABASE=laravel` to `DB_DATABASE=tiket_bioskop` like the configuration on the server side then it work ☹️.
Thank you

Comment: The error clearly says laravel database. So the client one throws it not the api one. Also do not use app debug true on public projects.

Comment: I did but the client is still trying to fetch the data from the client database, not from the response given by the API server

Comment: is DB_PORT and DB_HOST that run on the same address maybe the factor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this the error i got on client side SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = dimitri@gmail.com limit 1) and  $user = User::where('email' , $validate['email'])->firstOrFail(); and this code that causing the error, where the code is in a function on the server side, but the database configuration on the server side is approprieate, executing from POSTMAN it runs fine, but errors when I try from the client side website

Answer (score 0):

Create laravel db schema and run migrations on client side.

Comment: I did but still the client side tries to fetch the data from database on client side, data should be fetched from server side after making request to API endpoint

Comment: Laravel needs that. And it is not the api data.

Comment: Try to comment       Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class, from config/app.php and 'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class, and 'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I can't find these lines in the config/app.php file

Comment: Lumen can be used without db. I never used laravel without one. Search those clases in whole project.

Comment: okay thanks for helping I'll try your suggestion